# Diferent settings files for the same spring-boot project

Tags: spring-boot, application.properties

Could I have 2 different settings files for the same spring-boot project, with different setting on each one? My goal is have one `application.properties` file on the usual place (`src/main/resources`), with settings for spring-security and thymeleaf, for instance, and the another being created when the application is launched for the first time, with settings related to the datasource and jpa/hibernate.

this second file will be created after some sort of "installation wizard", where the user would be asked for the database connection data (like url, username and password), and saved in the outside locations for properties files. After that, the application should create the database, and export the entities on the model layer to tables on the database, like would happen if I have used the optin `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create` on an embed `application.properties` file.

Anyone knows if something like this is possible? If so, how to accomplish that?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that using the `spring.config.additional-location` property.

For example: `java -jar myproject.jar --spring.config.additional-location=/etc/java/myapp/config/`

See the doc [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files)

Comment: Can I do that without the command line option? I need a option that works with WAR files too. If I save the file on the pre-defined directories listed on the indicated link (like `/config`), the spring will load both files (the located on the `classpath` and the located on the /config` directory)?

Comment: You can use environment variable or system variable to use with the WAR file. And yes, spring boot will load both application.properties file from classpath and the file defined in the spring.config.additional-location property.